# Adding Seconds together

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

Im trying to add seconds like this

```
$h = str_replace("h ",":","$totalTime");
$m = str_replace("m ",":","$h");
$all = str_replace("s","","$m");

$parsed = date_parse($all);
$seconds = $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];

echo $seconds;
```

the results come out like this

12766 0 4460 0 9219 0 0

which i think is good because there are seven results 12766 , 0 ,  4460 , 0 , 9219 , 0 , 0
i want to add them but keep in mind that they are in sign of an array. 
I've been trying this $seconds * 7; or $seconds + seconds + seconds + seconds + seconds + seconds +seconds but i get this

89362 0 31220 0 64533 0 0

is there a way to add them all up and get just on value of seconds?

like 3294242

this is all the code

```
$query = "SELECT date, start, end, day_total, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, end) as day_t
          FROM `timesheet`
          WHERE `date` >= CAST('$start' AS DATE)
            AND `date` <= DATE_ADD(CAST('$start' AS DATE), INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND e_user='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

//Dump results into an array
$records = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $records[$row['date']] = $row;
}

//Create a loop from first to last date
//for each day, check if there is a matching records
//in the records array. If so, use that data
//Else, there was no data for that date

for($day=0; $day<7; $day++)
{
    $timeStamp = strtotime("{$start} +{$day} day");
    $dateStamp = date("Y-m-d", $timeStamp);
    $DOW       = date("D", $timeStamp);
    $dateStr   = date("m/d/Y", $timeStamp);

    //Set default values
    $startTime = '';
    $endTime = '';
    $totalHours = '';
    if(isset($records[$dateStamp]))
    {
        $startTime = $records[$dateStamp]['start'];
        $endTime   = $records[$dateStamp]['end'];
        $totalTimeer = $records[$dateStamp]['day_t'];
    } 
        // $totalTime = $records[$dateStamp]['day_total'];
        $totalTime = $records[$dateStamp]['day_total'];

$h = str_replace("h ",":","$totalTime");
$m = str_replace("m ",":","$h");
$all = str_replace("s","","$m");

$parsed = date_parse($all);
$seconds = $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];
$seconds += $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];
echo $seconds;
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some more code? Specifically about this array with seven results. Or do you just mean the results of date_parse()?

Comment: that looks like a string. just do this. `array_sum(explode(" ", $the_output_string))` or if it really is an array, just `array_sum($the_array)` [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: $seconds += $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second']; this will add second up each time you run this portion of your script.

Comment: If the output is a string, then pala_'s answer looks good

Comment: looks good for both now ;)

Comment: didn't work i will add the rest of the code

Comment: Your for-loop keeps echoing seconds one after the other, and your `$seconds = $parsed['hour'] ` bit resets it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-loop keeps echoing seconds one after the other, and your `$seconds = $parsed['hour']` bit resets it each time. Possible fix:

```
$seconds = 0;
for($day=0; $day<7; $day++)
{
   ...
   $seconds += $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];
}
echo $seconds;
```